# Turing-complete primitive blind automata

Tags: automata-theory, graph-theory, computer-science, lambda-calculus

Let $N$ be the set of natural numbers, $S$ be the set of finite binary sequences, and

$Q = [N \rightarrow N] \times [N \rightarrow N],$

where $[N \rightarrow N]$ is the set of all computable functions on natural numbers.

Then, let us consider the family of *primitive blind automata*

$A_p = (Q, \{p\}, Q, \delta, \delta)$

parameterized by a pair $p \in S \times S, \quad$ whose transition function is defined as follows:

$δ(f_0, f_1, x_1 \dots x_m, y_1 \dots y_n) = (f_0, f'_1), \quad$ where

$f'_1(k) = f_{y_n}(\dots f_{y_1}(1) \dots), \quad$ when $k = f_{x_m}(\dots f_{x_1}(1) \dots);$

$f'_1(k) = f_1(k), \quad$ when $k \neq f_{x_m}(\dots f_{x_1}(1) \dots).$

Are there Turing-complete primitive blind automata?

We are looking for $p$ of minimal length that makes $A_p$ Turing-complete.

### Remarks

The input alphabet is a set of one element. The output is the current state. Let us notice that for any pair $p \in S \times S, \quad$ there are states of $A_p$ that do not change during transition. Thus, one option of halt is to reach a dead-end state. In other words, the computation stops when the current state is a fixed point for the transition function. Such automata are Turing-complete iff there is a way to encode any recursive function into an initial state, for example in the form of lambda terms or interaction nets by Lafont. The encoding has to be an algorithm that eventually halts for any lambda term or any equivalent structure.

Each state $q = (f_0, f_1)$ of a primitive blind automaton can also be described itself as an automaton

$M_{f_0, f_1} = (N, \{0, 1\}, N, \phi_{f_0, f_1}, \phi_{f_0, f_1}), \quad$ where $\phi_{f_0, f_1}(n, b) = f_b(n).$

Alternatively, each state $(f_0, f_1)$ can be thought of as an infinite directed graph with exactly two arrows from each node, the arrows being labeled $0$ and $1. \quad$ The node corresponding to the natural number 1 is considered as the root node of the graph. During transition, the first binary sequence in $p$ represents a path (from the root node) to the node whose arrow labeled $1$ is changed to point to the node through the path corresponding to the second binary sequence in $p.$

For example, let $q = (f_0, f_1)$ and $p = (10, 011). \quad$ Then, in the graph $q′ = \delta(q, p)$ the arrow labeled $1$ from the node $f_0(f_1(1))$ points to the node $f_1(f_1(f_0(1))), \quad$ and this arrow is the only difference between the graphs $q$ and $q'.$

So far, we have found $(1111, 11010)$ as a possible candidate for a universal primitive blind automaton. For this pair of binary sequences, the states not necessary leading to a dead-end state break into the following three types.

1. When $f_1(f_1(1)) = 1.$
2. When $f_1(f_1(f_1(1))) = 1.$
3. When $f_1(f_1(f_1(f_1(1)))) = 1.$

In a state of type (2), a node $f_1(1) \neq 1$ changes; let us call it "writing". In turn, (1) and (3) change the root node; let us call them "next". (1) and (2) leave a node whose arrow labeled 1 points to the root node, while (3) leaves a linked list of three nodes ending with the root node. Thus, a rewriting scenario is possible for an arbitrary node $n. \quad$ Namely, there is a state that leads to "writing" $n, \quad$ switching "next" to some other node $x \neq n, \quad$ switching back to $n$, and "writing" $n$ again with another value.

Although the question about universality of $A_{1111, 11010}$ still remains open, we found that if the first binary sequence in the pair is shorter than $1111, \quad$ then there will not be any rewriting scenarios for an arbitrary node.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, i.e. what it would mean that this model is Turing-complete:
-what it the input of such an automaton ?
-when does the computation stops ?
-what is the output ?

Comment: The input alphabet is a set of one element. The output is the current state. The computation stops when the current state is a fixed point for the transition function. Such automata are Turing-complete iff there is a way to encode recursive functions into its initial states.

Comment: It would help if you explain what is primitive blind automaton "in words" rather than in symbols. This is the first time I see it and I cannot understand how it works. 

Comment: Each state (f_0, f_1) can be thought of as a directed graph with exactly two arrows from each node, the arrows being labeled 0 and 1. One node is considered as the root node of the graph. During transition, the first binary sequence in p represents a path (from the root node) to the node whose arrow labeled 1 is changed to point to the node through the path corresponding to the second binary sequence in p. 

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what a transition does. If $A$ is a labeled graph as you described, $p=(101,0111)$. Then what is the result of the transition. I guess it is a new graph $A'$. What is the difference between $A$ and $A'$. 

Comment: Let `$A = (f_0, f_1) \in (N \rightarrow N) \times (N \rightarrow N)$` and `$p = (101, 0111)$`. We consider natural number 1 as the root node. Then, in the graph `$A' = \delta(A, p)$` the arrow labeled 1 from the node `$f_1(f_0(f_1(1)))$` points to the node `$f_1(f_1(f_1(f_0(1))))$`.

Comment: It seems to me that, in the final paragraph, beginning "For example," the second sentence, "We consider natural number 1 as the root node", is not just part of the description of the example but rather a general convention intended to always be in force.  That is, the phrase "root node" in the preceding paragraph already refers just to the node 1.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, the original definition does indeed imply that in the suggested graph interpretation of the primitive blind automata, the root node is always the natural number 1.

Comment: So is it correct that the "states" of the machine are finite pointed complete deterministic automata with alphabet $\\{0,1\\}$ and moves replaces the out-edge labeled by 1 of one vertex by another edge labeled by 1? If this is so, then the moves do not change the number of vertices of the automaton. Therefore the machine is not Turing-complete. In fact it is equivalent to a (very large) finite automaton. 

Comment: The graph corresponding to a state `$q = (f_0, f_1) \in (N \rightarrow N) \times (N \rightarrow N)$` of a primitive blind automaton has infinite number of vertices, and infinite number of arrows. I assume that implies that the state cannot be described as a finite-state machine.

Comment: OK. So the states are infinite pointed (rooted) complete deterministic automata with alphabet $\{0,1\}$, transitions correspond to finite number of  pairs of words $(p,q)$. A transition corresponding to $p,q$ 
connects the end vertices $u, v$ of paths labeled by $p,q$ by an edge labeled by 1 and removes the old edge labeled by 1 starting at u. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I think such representation can indeed be seen equivalent for the definition of primitive blind automata, except that the input alphabet is only one pair of binary sequences. For a finite set of pairs, we already have constructed a Turing-complete machine that simulates directed interaction combinators by Lafont, the input being one fixed repeating sequence of total about hundred pairs.

Comment: I see, so the problem is whether you can construct a universal machine this way using only one transition. At least now I understand what the problem is. I doubt this is universal (because a Turing machine with one command, and other similar devices, like groups with one defining relation, are not universal), but this is not a very strong doubt. The question is interesting. 

Comment: One more question: when does the machine stop?

Comment: Let us notice that for any pair of binary sequences, there are graphs that do not change during transion. Thus, one option of halt is to reach a dead-end state. Alternatively, if we simulate some TRS, for instance lambda calculus or interaction nets, we can instead dedicate to outside world to check if the current state corresponds to a normal form.

Comment: So far, we managed to find a pair `$(1111, 11010)$` as a candidate of the minimal length. For this pair, the possible states not necessarily leading to a dead-end state break into three types: 1) `$f_1(f_1(1)) = 1$`, 2) `$f_1(f_1(f_1(1))) = 1$`, and 3) `$f_1(f_1(f_1(f_1(1)))) = 1$`. In a state of type (2), a node `$f_1(1)$` changes; let us call it "write". In turn, (1) and (3) change the root node; let us call them "next". (1) and (2) leave a node whose arrow labeled 1 points to the root node, while (3) leaves a linked list of the three nodes. We have rewriting scenarios for an arbitrary node.

Comment: You proved that the pair $(1111,11010)$ is universal?


Comment: The question about universality of `$A_{1111, 11010}$` still remains open. What we found is that if the first binary sequence in the pair is shorter than `$1111, \quad$` there will not be any rewriting scenarios for an arbitrary node.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_machine - looks like my contruction is (nearly) the same as Schönhage's Storage Modification Machine (SMM) model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The construction is similar to that of [Schönhage's Storage Modification Machine (SMM) model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_machine#Sch.C3.B6nhage.27s_Storage_Modification_Machine_.28SMM.29_model).

Answer (score 1):

Probably I also don't understand the question but then by universality you mean that Q can change or that p can change? I think both cases are easy to be seen to be universal but I must misunderstand something.

In the first, pick p=(1,11) and let the integers correspond to the steps of your favorite Turing-machine such that you take some computable injection from (x-tape content, s-machine state, h-position of head) to the integers. In this case Q will be also nice, you don't even need the 0's.

If Q is fixed, then proceed similar as before, except now encode (T-description of TM,x,s,h) into the integers and p will have some form like (00001,000011) where the first k zeros take us to the start conditions of the k-th TM.

I also suggest that you try posting your problem on https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ instead of MO.

Comment: The suggested structure for an initial state of `$A_{1, 11}$` is unfortunately not an encoding for recursive functions due to the halting problem. The encoding has to be an algorithm that eventually halts for any lambda term.

Comment: Well, I told you I probably don't understand the question...

Comment: With the current definition of primitive blind automata, one computable function `$f_1$` can indeed simulate a universal Turing machine having its tapes enumerated. Thus, `$A_{1, 111}$` is Turing-complete with encoding being one edge `$f_1(1) = x$` where `$x$` corresponds to the initial tape of the Turing machine for a given recursive function. As we are looking for initial states `$(f_0, f_1)$` that would be simple in some sense, we need to rethink the definition and come up with a more precise version of our question.